# Prestashop module ProductComments

Tags: prestashop

I am trying to adapt the Product Comments "add a review feature" (which is on the Product page) to work on the Products List page, but the link is only recognizing the first product in the list. There is a pencil icon link next to each product in the list, but they all link to the first product only.

Can anybody let me know why this is happening, and point me in the right direction to fixing it.

Following is the code in my custom hook:

```
include_once dirname(__FILE__).'/ProductComment.php';
    include_once dirname(__FILE__).'/ProductCommentCriterion.php';

if(in_array($this->context->controller->php_self, array('product-list'))) $products = Product::getProducts((int) Tools::getValue('id_product'), $this->context->language->id);
{

    $id_guest = (!$id_customer = (int) $this->context->cookie->id_customer) ? (int) $this->context->cookie->id_guest : false;
    $customerComment = ProductComment::getByCustomer((int) (Tools::getValue('id_product')), (int) $this->context->cookie->id_customer, true, (int) $id_guest);
    $average = ProductComment::getAverageGrade((int) Tools::getValue('id_product'));
    $image = Product::getCover((int) Tools::getValue('id_product'));
    $cover_image = $this->context->link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $image['id_image'], 'medium_default');

    $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
        'id_product_comment_form' => (int) Tools::getValue('id_product'),
        'product' => $products,
        'secure_key' => $this->secure_key,
        'logged' => $this->context->customer->isLogged(true),
        'allow_guests' => (int) Configuration::get('PRODUCT_COMMENTS_ALLOW_GUESTS'),
        'productcomment_cover' => (int) Tools::getValue('id_product').'-'.(int) $image['id_image'], // retro compat
        'productcomment_cover_image' => $cover_image,
        'mediumSize' => Image::getSize(ImageType::getFormatedName('medium')),
        'criterions' => ProductCommentCriterion::getByProduct((int) Tools::getValue('id_product'), $this->context->language->id),
        'action_url' => '',
        'averageTotal' => round($average['grade']),
        'ratings' => ProductComment::getRatings((int) Tools::getValue('id_product')),
        'too_early' => ($customerComment && (strtotime($customerComment['date_add']) + Configuration::get('PRODUCT_COMMENTS_MINIMAL_TIME')) > time()),
        'nbComments' => (int) (ProductComment::getCommentNumber((int) Tools::getValue('id_product'))),
   ));
    return $this->display(__FILE__, '/mytemplate.tpl');
    }
```

This is the code in my template:

```
<SCRIPT>
$(document).ready(function() {  

if (!!$.prototype.fancybox)
    $('.open-comment-form').fancybox({
     'autoSize' : false,
     'width': 800,
     'height': auto,
     'hideOnContentClick': false,
     'title' : null,            
}); 
}); 
</SCRIPT>

{if (!$too_early AND ($is_logged OR ($PRODUCT_COMMENTS_ALLOW_GUESTS == 0)))}    
<p class="align_center">
    <a class="open-comment-form" href="#new_comment_form" title="{l s='Write your review' mod='productcomments'}!"></a>
</p>
{/if}
```

I am using Prestashop version 1.6.1.14. Thanks aussiecomet

Comment: It has been 13 days since I asked this question and I still have no reply. Isn't there anyone out there who can help with this problem? I don't want you to solve it, just tell me what has to be done, and I will do it, after all that is how you learn. I can give more details, but not until someone shows an interest in helping. Thanks.

aussiecomet

Comment: Well you could give more details obviously, maybe some code of how you are generating the links. Version of Prestashop you're using would also help. How do you expect people to help when you're basically asking "Why isn't this working?" without any specific details whatsover. You don't go to a mechanic and just tell him "My car isn't working..." right?

Comment: I'll give it one more try. I still have no answer for this problem. Is no body interested in helping!!

Comment: I didn't even see you edited your question until you posted comment. Two things that jump right out is here `Product::getProducts((int) Tools::getValue('id_product'), $this->context->language->id);` Don't know how are you getting `id_product` value when you are in product list, maybe it's there as first product so that's your first problem. And second problem is you have method parameters wrong. Look [here](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/classes/Product.php#L1190) for the method parameters.

Comment: Thank you for giving me something to work with. It is very late here in Australia, so I will work on it tomorrow. Thanks again!

Comment: I still cannot get this to work. I think it is beyond my abilities! Either that, or it is not possible.